# How to simulate an AnAction about IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm writing the test case about IntelliJ plugin, but now i dont know how to simulate an AnAction to test this

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent anActionEvent)
```

Comment: Have you looked into intellij-community sources?

Comment: yes, i find that in the plugins folder, there are some plugins source and test case, but i dont find the test case about the AnActionEvent. So i ask if someone knows how to simulate the event.